# Could you have multiple ways to run a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am setting up a database package in Node.js and would like to not have separate functions for writing to the database like this:
    `write(key, val)` and     `write({key: val, key2: val2})`. I've seen other solutions on Stack Overflow and other websites and would like to have the simplest solution so my function would "know" whether it was a key, val pair or a JSON object. For example:

```
if (argtype == "kvp") { // key val pair
    databaseJSON[key] = val;
    flushToDB(databaseJSON);
} else {
    let j = databaseJSON;
    for (let i in Object.values(obj)) j[Object.keys(obj)[i]] = Object.values(obj)[i];
    flushToDB(databaseJSON);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two arguments are passed, just assign the `val` to the `key` property of the database, otherwise `Object.assign` the one argument to the database, to put all of its properties and values from the passed object to the database:

```
function write(key, val) {
  if (val !== undefined) {
    database[key] = val;
  } else {
    Object.assign(database, key);
  }
  flushToDB(database)
}
```

```js
const database = {};
const flushToDB = db => console.log('flushing');

function write(key, val) {
  if (val !== undefined) {
    database[key] = val;
  } else {
    Object.assign(database, key);
  }
  flushToDB(database)
}


write('key', 'val');
console.log('db:', database);
write({ key2: 'val2', key3: 'val3' });
console.log('db:', database);
```

Because the database here is a plain object, not JSON (something in JSON format is a *string*, which is not the case here), better to call it `database` rather than `databaseJSON`. (See [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/))

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
function foo() {
  if (arguments.length == 1) {
    // use your object code on arguments[0]
    let j = databaseJSON;
    let obj = arguments[0]
    for (let i in Object.values(obj))
      j[Object.keys(obj)[i]] = Object.values(obj)[i];
    flushToDB(databaseJSON);
  } else {
      //user arguments[0] and arguments[1] for you key value
     databaseJSON[arguments[0]] = arguments[1];
    flushToDB(databaseJSON);
  }
}
```

You can also throw error if arguments.length == 0